# PHP Echo with System Command

Tags: php, variables, echo

i need to call a variable ($id) within a php system command. I'm automating a solr curl delete command, and it works with a static id, but i need to echo the $id so it deletes the correct document.

code is:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

$last_line = system('curl http://localhost:8983/solr/imagedb/update?commit=true --data \'<delete><query>id\:<?php echo $id; ?></query></delete>\' -H \'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8\'', $retval);

// Printing additional info
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

The code shows no error but the document is not deleted so it is not grabbing the $id variable. Its an echo within a php system command. How to make it work?

Comment: We can't see here `$id` is defined, so it's likely we can't help you with why `$id` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `<?php echo $id; ?>` inside a string. That only works when you're out of PHP execution mode. Use string concatenation.

```
$last_line = system('curl http://localhost:8983/solr/imagedb/update?commit=true --data \'<delete><query>id\:' . $id . '</query></delete>\' -H \'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8\'', $retval);
```

Comment: bingo! interestingly the slight difference in syntax between your and zejur answer made a difference. ' . $id . ' worked but '.$id.' didn't. thank you both.

Comment: There's no difference. Spaces around `.` are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `php` tags and enclose a variable in single quotes in your `system` call. Now your `variable` along with php tags is passed as a string.

so update this line:

```
$last_line = system('curl http://localhost:8983/solr/imagedb/update?commit=true --data \'<delete><query>id\:<?php echo $id; ?></query></delete>\' -H \'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8\'', $retval);
```

to:

```
$last_line = system('curl http://localhost:8983/solr/imagedb/update?commit=true --data \'<delete><query>id\:'.$id.'</query></delete>\' -H \'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8\'', $retval);
```